# can I create multiple Google play developer account with same credit card?

Tags: android

I wanna know if one of my account gets banned,will it affect second one, since both are created using same debit card?

Answer (score 7):

You can have multiple developer accounts.

If one account get banned Google will try to find all your other accounts and they will be banned too..

> After your account has been terminated
>
> When your developer account is terminated, all applications in your
>   catalog will be removed from the Google Play store and the users,
>   stats, and ratings associated with those applications will be
>   forfeited. Additionally, you will no longer be able to publish new
>   applications. Please do not attempt to register for a new Google Play
>   Developer Console account.
>
> If your account was terminated for violating the developer terms, we
>   can no longer accept applications from you. This means that any
>   related accounts are also permanently suspended, and any new accounts
>   that you try to open will be terminated without a refund of the
>   developer registration fee.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2491922?hl=en&ref_topic=3453554

It will effect if they find them.